# Model Properties passing as nulls to Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to pass an item with the type "EmployeeDocument" to my action but all of values are coming back as nulls and I am not sure why. I have tried passing the entire model as well as just pieces and they are all null and I am not sure why this is happening.

Here is what my view looks like:

```
    <table id="results-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <u>@Html.DisplayName("Title")</u>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <u>@Html.DisplayName("Document Type")</u>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <u>@Html.DisplayName("Created By")</u>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <u>@Html.DisplayName("Created Date")</u>
                </th>
                <th style="width: 180px;"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DocumentType)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="@item.FullUrl">View</a> | @Html.ActionLink("Replace", "ReplaceEmployeeDocument", "Employee",new {title = item.Title, doctype = item.DocumentType, createdDate = item.CreatedDate,createdBy = item.CreatedBy, fullUrl = item.FullUrl}) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteEmployeeDocument",new {fileName = item.FullUrl, employeeNo = item.EmployeeNumber})</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am focusing on the replace action link in the table.

This is what my action looks like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ReplaceEmployeeDocument(string title, string doctype, DateTime createdDate, string createdBy, string fullUrl)
    {
        var doc = new EmployeeDocument();
        return PartialView(doc);
    }
```

All of the parameters in the action are null. Is there a reason why these are like that?

Comment: user3788671, Can you post the actionLink that is calling ReplaceEmployeeDocument? Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to post back a collection of objects, in order for this to work you need to use a for loop and index the properties with hidden inputs as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ReplaceEmployeeDocument", "Controller"))
{
    @for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Title)
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Title)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].DocumentType)
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].DocumentType)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].CreatedBy)
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].CreatedBy)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].CreatedDate)
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].CreatedDate)
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="@item.FullUrl">View</a> | <input type="submit" value="Replace"/></td>
                    </tr>
                }
}
```

You also need a corresponding post method that accepts the model being passed back:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReplaceEmployeeDocument(EmployeeDocument model)
{
    var doc = new EmployeeDocument();
    return PartialView(doc);
}
```

Comment: I dont think I can have a var i= 0 in my foreach. And when I change it to a for statement. And will i need to replace item. with m[i].?

Comment: @user3788671 sorry it was supposed to be a for, i've updated it.

Comment: okay, so basically what I am trying to do is keep this entire model the same besides one property which is named FullURL. When the user pushes the replace button in the table i want there to pop up a box for the user to select a file and replace the FullUrl with the new one from the pop up. Is this still the best way to do this?

Comment: @user3788671 I'm not too sure from the comments it seems like a lot of info isn't in the question. It might be worth posting another question with a simplified example. You will get more people answering that way.

Answer (score 1):

You dont seem to be using any @Html.EditorFor which would generate input fields, and you dont have any form or javascript that would send your arguments in either GET or POST method. Therefore none of your fields are sent to the method in the controller. You should wrape the code inside the foreach in a

```
@Html.BeginForm() {}
```